# Use Passport token in web route Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have an API with Passport.

And if I call, from my frontend for example

> "api/getData"

And it works fine.
I send to my backend the access token and I can make check via middleware if user that makes a request is Logged or no.

Now If I would make a call to WEB route with passport token such as:

> "mysite/dowload/something"

Where in this route I want know if my user is Logged or not.

Can I do it with passport token?
Because the web routes have Session and Token no.
And obviously if I try to get user with:

> Auth::user()

In my controller I get a null value.

Can I check in web route if user is logged via token?

Comment: Sounds like you should move your mysite/dowload/something route to be in the API. Laravel uses middleware to do the authentication. You may be able to put multiple authentication guards on one route, but I'd think it would make sense to just move this to the API, since you're using API-style authentication.